# JavaScript addClass not working with PHP GET['page']

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have been attempting to implement the following javascript to set the last clicked list item with a class of 'active' and remove the class from other list items if applicable...

```
<script>
            $(function() {
                $('ul li').click( function() {
                    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                });
            });
        </script>
```

This code works on a static html page but when included with the following code I can't seem to get it to work...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>  
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            p{
                font-size: 32px;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align: center;
            }           
            #banner 
            {
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('ul li').click( function() {
                    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <img id="banner" src="Banner.png" />
        </div>

        <div class="container">
             <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"></a>
                </div>
                <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="index.php?page=home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php?page=music">Music</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php?page=videos">Videos</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>  
        </div>

        <?php
            if (isset($_GET['page'])) 
            {
                // include selected page into the current screen
                switch ($_GET['page']) 
                {
                    case 'home':
                        include("home.html");
                        break;
                    case 'music':
                        include("music.html");
                        break;
                    case 'videos':
                        include("videos.html");
                        break;
                    default:
                        include('home.html');
                }
            } 
            else 
            { // If no button has been selected, then display the default page
                include("home.html");
            }   
        ?>    
    </body>
</html>
```

I can write (and have written) the same functionality using PHP, however, I would like to understand why this code isn't working, does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attaching a click event when the page is navigating won't allow the jQuery to perform.

Instead, add an active class on the list item when the php executes.

`<li class="<?php echo ($_GET['page']=='home')?'active':'';?>"> </li>`

---

*Replace your menu with the code below*

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="<?php echo ($_GET['page']=='home')?'active':'';?>"><a href="index.php?page=home">Home</a></li>
      <li class="<?php echo ($_GET['page']=='music')?'active':'';?>"><a href="index.php?page=music">Music</a></li>
      <li class="<?php echo ($_GET['page']=='videos')?'active':'';?>"><a href="index.php?page=videos">Videos</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window.load

```
$(window).load(function(){  
        $('ul li').click( function() {
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');    
        });
});
```

Or if you are using jquery, use document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('ul li').click( function() {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Not working, I think the values are getting reset with the php page includes but I am not sure